# How do you upload an image to server after drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html, servlets, drag-and-drop

I have this whole drag and drop thing working, but how do you upload it to the server???  I can get the dataURL of the image which is some base64 encoding.  Is there way to upload this to my servlet and how will the servlet accept this?  [This tutorial](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/html5-drag-and-drop-and-file-api-tutorial/) was helpful but it's missing the uploading portion.  I've also looked at other JQuery plugins which seemed to customized and heavy for my use.

Comment: Where did the image come from originally?

Comment: @Diodeus From the user desktop.

Comment: So how are you using the image if the user has not ALREADY uploaded it to the server?

Comment: I don't I was clear.  I have the image stored locally on my machine(desktop).  I want to upload it to the server after I drag and drop it from my desktop to my browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more searching, I found out that it's very easy to submit a file using JavaScript's `FormData` object.  After you get the image file from `dataTransfer.files`, which part of the drag and drop API, the following code able to successfully send the image file to the server.

```
// Create formdata object
var formData = new FormData;
// Append form item (key, value)
formData.append('file', imageFile);

// JQuery ajax call to submit the file using post request
$.ajax({
    url: 'url_of_server_script',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One options would be to use this:

http://www.plupload.com/

While it does come with a UI, it also comes with JS library were you can send your file to a server programmatically.  The UI and programmatic portions are separate js files so you won't have to clutter your website with unnecessary JS...

I'm a big advocate of not reinventing wheels...:-)

Comment: Yeah, I'm using plupload on one of my projects too.  I also like how it degrades gracefully if the browser doesn't support HTML5 for drag/drop.

If nothing else, if you just want to know for yourself, take a look at the plupload code and see how they are handling it.